# Remove data jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a form which I build for an AJAX query as below:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
```

If I want to remove a input element from myForm can I do this:

I had tried $('#myForm')[0].elementToRemove.remove(); but I get an error in console saying object doesnt support the property or method.

So I require something like :

```
$('#myForm')[0] // remove an input element here
// now build the formData with that element removed
var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

look at [jQuery.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) properly, you should use it as:

```
$("your-selector").remove();
```

like:

```
$("#myForm").remove("input[name='your_input_name']");
```